# Invisible cells of UICollectionView are not deselected - Swift

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, didselectrowatindexpath

I have in my swift app two collection views. One which is a functions categories and another one which is the functions. The first one works as a filter to the second one. If I select "Cat1" then only functions with tag "Cat1" are displayed. This works great.
The functions categories collectionview is horizontal and I need to scroll to see all the cells. My issue/problem is already mentioned in another topics but I can not find the right anwser or technique.

Issue: If I select a category, the cell's background changes, fine. If now I scroll completely to the end of the collectionview and select the last cell, this one change as selected the the first one (previously selected) is not deselected.. I know that is a problem with reused cell but no idea how to manage that. Below my code :

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
// Working with functions categories collection view
      if collectionView == self.functionsCategoriesCollectionView {
          let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as! DevicePageFunctionsCategoriesCVCell
              cell.isHidden = false
              cell.cellView.isHidden = false
              cell.isSelected = true

              cell.cellView.clipsToBounds = true
              cell.cellView.layer.cornerRadius = 25
              cell.cellView.addGradiant(colors: [UIColor(red: 127.0/255.0, green: 127.0/255.0, blue: 127.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0).cgColor, UIColor(red: 47.0/255.0, green: 47.0/255.0, blue: 47.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0).cgColor], angle: 45)

          if cellSelectionIndexPath == indexPath {
              // it was already selected
              cellSelectionIndexPath = nil
              collectionView.deselectItem(at: indexPath, animated: true)
              cell.cellView.addGradiant(colors: [UIColor.clear.cgColor, UIColor.clear.cgColor], angle: 0)

              self.filtered = GlobalVariables.currentProduct.functions.filter { _ in
                  return true
              }

              self.functionsCollectionView.reloadData()

          } else {
              // wasn't yet selected, so let's remember it
              cellSelectionIndexPath = indexPath

              // Filter with seletec category name
              let cellCategoryName = ICDatabase.objects(FunctionCategory.self)[indexPath.row]

              self.filtered = GlobalVariables.currentProduct.functions.filter { function in
                  return function.functionCategory.contains(cellCategoryName)
              }

              self.functionsCollectionView.reloadData()
          }

      }
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didDeselectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        if collectionView == self.functionsCategoriesCollectionView {

            if let cellToDeselect = collectionView.cellForItem(at: self.cellSelectionIndexPath) as? DevicePageFunctionsCategoriesCVCell {

                cellToDeselect.isSelected = false

                collectionView.deselectItem(at: self.cellSelectionIndexPath, animated: true)

                cellToDeselect.cellView.addGradiant(colors: [UIColor.clear.cgColor, UIColor.clear.cgColor], angle: 0)

                self.cellSelectionIndexPath = nil

                // Get all functions
                self.filtered = GlobalVariables.currentProduct.functions.filter { _ in
                    return true
                }

                self.functionsCollectionView.reloadData()
            }
        }
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: As always: **Manage the selection in the data model, don't manipulate the cells directly**. Then the proper UI states will be set reliably in `itemForRowAt`. Everything else is cumbersome and error-prone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this -

```
var selectedIndexPath: IndexPath?

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath)

        cell.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.black

        self.selectedIndexPath = indexPath
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didDeselectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath)

        cell.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

        self.selectedIndexPath = nil
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but this do exactly the same as my actual code

Comment: @Silvering What did you did in cellForItemAt(indexPath)

Comment: https://gist.github.com/MickaelCruzDB/22d11e657e7b24546759c874236f8127

Comment: I edited my gist : https://gist.github.com/MickaelCruzDB/8bcd0c4c7bd29206f0dac6b2af2ad711

Answer (score 0):

Collection cells reuse memory. So you have to manually manage data and UI. If your requirement is to select only one category cell in collection view at any time, keep one variable in collection view and update it in didSelect method.

```
var selectedIndexPath: IndexPath?

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    selectedIndexPath = indexPath
    collectionView.reloadData()
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = UICollectionCell()
    ....
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
    if indexPath == selectedIndexPath {
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    } 
}
```

Comment: I created a gist with your proposal : https://gist.github.com/MickaelCruzDB/8bcd0c4c7bd29206f0dac6b2af2ad711 But I can not manage to have fix my issue